# не выводится пароль для каждого пользователя

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый вечер. У меня есть база на sqlite, comboBox и textbox. в comboBox имена двух пользователей. При выборе пользователей в comboBox, в textbox должен появляться пароль этого пользователя. У меня при выборе второго пользователя появляется пароль первого пользователя в textbox и больше не изменяется пароль в textbox.

Вот код:

```
private void comboBoxLogin_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string query = "SELECT Password FROM users WHERE Id=@id";
        connection.Open();
        command = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", comboBoxLogin.SelectedIndex);
        SQLiteDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        if(dr.Read())
        {
            switch (comboBoxLogin.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0: textBoxPassword.Text = dr["Password"].ToString(); break;
                case 1: textBoxPassword.Text = dr["Password"].ToString(); break;
            }
        }
        dr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
    finally
    {

        connection.Close();
    }  
}
```

Comment: несколько рекомендаций
1. Не игнорируйте  исключение  catch (Exception ex) {Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }.
 В окне вывод при отладке туда попадут сообщения исключения.
2. Считанное значение сразу не присваивать на textBoxPassword, а воспользоваться дополнительной переменой. C вас не убудет и код лучше выглядеть будет

Comment: Проблемы не вижу.
Только отладкой можно решить

Comment: можно так. Создать переменный string и запихнуть в switch, потом присвоит в textbox.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что `switch` здесь лишний

```
private void comboBoxLogin_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string query = "SELECT Password FROM users WHERE Id=@id";
        connection.Open();
        command = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", comboBoxLogin.SelectedIndex);
        SQLiteDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        // Используйте подобные переменные для промежуточных значений
        // Повышает читабельность кода            
        string password = string.Empty;
        if(dr.Read())
        {
           // Конструкция switch была лишней, вы и так передали параметр в запросе
           password = dr["Password"].ToString(); 

        }
        dr.Close();


        textBoxPassword.Text = password;
    }
    // Не игнорируйте исключения
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        // Это сообщение попадет в "окно вывода" при отладке
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {

        connection.Close();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Теперь когда выбираю второго пароль первого появляется у второго, а у первого ничего

Comment: @ИсмоилМухаммадиев 
Проверьте на отладке значение **int selectIndex = comboBoxLogin.SelectedIndex;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", selectIndex);** Возможно неверные данные заходят

Comment: проверил,  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", selectIndex); индекс показывает 1. Это когда я второго выбрал.

Comment: Вариант: ваши пользователи имеют id =  1..2, в то время как comboBoxLogin.SelectedIndex начинает отсчет с 0..1. 
Т.е. перед тем как передать параметр увеличить его на 1 
**selectIndex = selectIndex +  1;**

Comment: @CuprumBurСпасибо большое сработало, почему в голову не пришло что comboBox начинается с нуля)))

Comment: try использовать нужно, но... Учитесь пользоваться проверками, не кидайте все в try!!!

Comment: @Александр Пузанов Ок.